# How to include a Python dataset in a question

Tags: support, asking-questions

I used `dput` in R previously, which would output a statement to recreate any data object in R. I would put this code in Stack Overflow and another user could paste it into R and the data object would be created.

What's the best way to post a sample dataset for Python on Stack Overflow? Is there a method or package to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For formatting any python list/dictionary, it's probably best to use the built in pretty printing library (`pprint`) Here's an example of a console session:

```
>>> d = { 'Key1':'Value1', 'Key2':'Value2', 'Key3':'Value3', "Key4":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] }
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(d)
{'Key1': 'Value1',
 'Key2': 'Value2',
 'Key3': 'Value3',
 'Key4': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}
```

The dictionary, as you can see, is nicely formatted for readability, and is fairly easy to copy and paste into a editor to use.

This does assume that the objects you're using are iterable, or at least have reasonable repr strings.

Also keep in mind that data included to support a question should be the minimum amount of data necessary to reproduce the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you! I also just found df[:5].to_dict(), which seems to be another good method for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this works well:

```
df[:5].to_dict()
```